# Which scripture was first to identify Buddha as an avatar of Lord Vishnu?

Tags: puranas, avatars, buddhism

Some puranas identify Buddha with Vishnu among them which is the oldest reference?

Answer (score 3):

Buddha in Dashavatara list in Narada Purana...

> निर्गुणाय निरीहाय नीतिज्ञायाक्रियात्मने ।
> बुद्धाय कल्किरूपाय क्षेत्रज्ञायाक्षराय च ॥ ३२-३६

> (Narada Purana -Uttarardh : Chapter 32: Verse 36 )...

English translation - He is transcendental, devoid of the modes of nature, and knows morality and is the Self of action. O Buddha and Kalki, and you are the knower of the field.
Even further, the description of Buddha and Kalki is described in the form of incarnations in Kali Yuga ....

"It is mentioned in Bhagvat Puran(Bhagvatam) 10 Skandha Chapter 40 on verse number 22 that

> "नमो बुद्धाय शुद्धाय दैत्य दानवमोहिने"।
> म्लेच्छ प्राय: क्षत्रहन्त्रे नमस्ते कल्कि रूपिणे"।।२२।

English translation - Obeisances to Your form as the faultless Lord Buddha, who will bewilder the Daityas and Dānavas, and to Lord Kalki, the annihilator of the meat-eaters posing as kings.

The description of Mahatma Buddha in the Mahabharata is as follows. Check from
Forty-seventh chapter page number 4536 on Shantiparva Raj-dharmanushasan-parb Bhishmastavaraj, respectively, in the Gita Press Edition.

> दानवांस्तु वशेकृत्वा पुनर्बुद्धत्वमागत:।
> सर्गस्य रक्षणार्थाय तस्मै बुद्धात्मने नम:।।
> हनिष्यति कलौ प्राप्ते म्लेच्‍छांस्तुरगवाहन:।
> धर्मसंस्थापको यस्तु तस्मै कल्क्यात्मने नम:।।

English translation- Salutations to Sri Hari in the form of Lord Buddha, those who take the demons under their control to protect the world and again incarnate as Buddha.Salutations to Shri Hari, the form of Kalki, who will kill the Demonic Mlechchas for the establishment of Dharma, riding on a horse at the arrival of Kali Yuga.

> काषायवस्रसंवीतो मुण्डितः शुक्लदन्तवान्।
> **शुद्धोदनसुतो** **बुद्धो** मोहयिष्यामि मानवान् ।।४३।
> ।

> (Gita press - Mahabharat: Shanti Parva :Chapter-348 verse 43 )

English translation - He will wearing light yellow clothes. He is knows as **Buddha, the son of King** **Shuddhodhana**, who will enchant the people.

It is prescribed in Bhavishya Purana:

> एतस्मिनैव काले तु कलिना संस्मृतो हरिः |
> काश्यपादुद्भवो देवो गौतमो नाम विश्रुतः |
> बौद्धधर्मं समाश्रित्य पट्टणे प्राप्तवान्हरिः |

> (Bhavishya Purana- Pratisarga Parva: Chapter 6 :Verse 36)

English translation - On the request of Kaliyuga, Lord Vishnu in the Kashyap gotra took an incarnation in the name of Gautam Buddha and went to Patna for expanding Buddhism.

This is also mentioned in Narasimha Purana‌

> कलौ प्राप्ते यथा बुद्धो भवेन्नारायणः प्रभुः"

> -(Narasimha Purana: Chapter-36 Verse-9 )

English Translation - Lord Narayana will take the form of Buddha on attaining Kali Yuga.

Lord Buddha mentioned in Dasavatara Stotra . Actually it is the need of that time so Viṣṇu taken Buddha Avatar to close all Vedas readings for sometime to Stop all evil in Society that started spreading that time slowly slowly like Narbali, Ashwabali , discrimination etc.. And after that Lord Viṣṇu ask Shiva to take Avatar (as Adi Shankaracharya) to demolish their Sunyavaad philosophy and re-open all Vedas —

> निन्दसि यज्ञविधेरहह श्रुतिजातं सदयहृदयदर्शितपशुघातं
> केशव धृतबुद्धशरीर जय जगदीश हरे ।।9।।

Translation — O Jagdishwar! having taken a Buddha's body you have denounced the Shruti(Vedas) after seeing the violence of animals by the sacrificial rituals by compassionate heart .Hail to you.

Shaivas famous Tantras — Maheshwara Tantra also mentioned about Buddhavtar of Shri Hari —

> तपश्चरसु सर्वेषु असुरेषु जयार्थिषु **विष्णुः** सुदुस्तरां मायामास्यास्य सुरनोदितः ॥ मोहयामास योगात्मा तपोविघ्नाय तान्प्रभुः स मूढान् **बुद्धरूपेण** तानुवाच महामनाः ॥ **शक्या जेतुं** सुराः सर्वे युष्माभिरितिदर्शनैः बौद्धधर्म समास्थाय शक्यास्ते बभूविरे ॥तानुवाचार्हतो मम यूयं भवत मद्विधाः । ज्ञानेन सहितं धर्म ते चार्हन्त इति स्मृताः ॥ बौद्धश्रावकनिर्ग्रथाः सिद्धपुत्रास्तथैव च । एते सर्वेपि चार्हंतो विज्ञेया दुष्टचारिणः ॥

> (Maheshwar Tantra, Chapter 8 , Verses 35-39)

Padma Puran claim the same that Sri Hari appeared as Lord Buddha appeared to destroy the demonic nature of peoples to save Dharma —

> दैत्यानां नाशनार्थाय विष्णुना बुद्धरूपिणा ।

> (Padma Purana, Uttarakhand, Chapter – 236, Verse – 06 )

Translation — Lord Viṣṇu, in the form of the Buddha, appeared to destroy the demonic peoples.

Read the prophecy of Lord Vishnu about Buddha -

> मया बुद्धेन वक्तव्या धर्माः कलियुगे पुनः ।

> (Vishnudharmottara Purana, Volume 3, Chapter 351, Verse - 54) -

> Translation -Lord Sri Hari says— I will preach the Dharma in Kali-yuga as Buddha.

Vayu Puran mentioned about Lord Buddha some family details-

> भविता सञ्जयश्चापि वीरो राजा रणञ्जयात् सञ्जयस्य सुतः शाक्यः शाक्याच्छुद्धोदनोऽभवत् ॥ शुद्धोदनस्य भविता शाक्यार्थे राहुलः स्मृतः । प्रसेनजित्ततो भाव्यः क्षुद्रको भविता ततः ॥

> (Vayu Purana, Uttraardh , Chapter - 37, Verse - 284-285)

Translation — Rananjay's son will be Sanjay. Sanjaya's son will be Shakya and from him will be Suddhodana. Shuddhodan's son become Rahul with the title Shakya. Rahul's son will be Prasenjit and his son will be Kshudraka.

Skanda Puran mentioned that Lord Viṣṇu will appear on earth as Buddha-

> तथा बुद्धत्वमपरं नवमं प्राप्स्यतेऽच्युतः । शान्तिमान्देवदेवेशो मधुहन्ता मधुप्रियः ॥ तेन बुद्धस्वरूपेण देवेन परमेष्ठिना । भविष्यति जगत्सर्वं मोहितं सचराचरम् ॥

> (Skanda Purana, Avantikhand-Rewakhand, Chapter-151, Verse 21-22)

Translation — Lord Achyutadeva (Vishnu) will arrive in the form of Buddha as the ninth incarnation. That form of the Lord, Vasantapriya (Kamarupi), the destroyer of Madhudaitya, will be peaceful. The whole world will be fascinated by that form of that Supreme God.'

Same thing about Buddhavtara is mentioned in Jyotish Shastra texts -

> अवताराण्यनेकानि ह्यजस्य परमात्मनः । जीवानां कर्मफलदो ग्रहरूपी जनार्दनः ॥ दैत्यानां बलनाशाय देवानां बलबृद्धये धर्मसंस्थापनार्थाय ग्रहाज्जाताः शुभाः क्रमात् ॥
> ………
> नृसिहो भूमिपुत्रस्य बुद्धः सोमसुतस्य च ॥ वामनो विबुधेज्यस्य भार्गवो भार्गवस्य च कूर्मो भास्करपुत्रस्य सैंहिकेयस्य सूकरः ॥

> (Brihatparashara Horashastra, Chapter 2, Verses 4-7 )

Translation — There are many incarnations of the unborn God. Lord Janardana(Narayana) also comes in the form of a planet to give the living beings the fruits of their actions. In order to destroy the power of the demons and to increase the power of the gods, for the establishment of religion, auspicious planets have been created in order. ……. Buddha incranation is represented by planet Mercury , Vamana Jupiter , Parashuramavatar Venus , Kurmaavatar Saturn .

Why Lord Buddha is not worship by Sanatanis? The answer of this question is given in Uppurana —

> तथापि पूजया हीनो बभूव बुद्धरूपधृक् । विष्णुर्वेदविरुद्धस्थमार्गसंसर्जनात्किल ॥

> (Mudgal Upapurana, Volume 8, Chapter - 15)

> Translation — Due to the establishment of the path against the Vedas, Lord Vishnu was devoid of worship in the form of Buddha .

Agni Puran mentioned that all Devas request Lord Narayana to appear on earth to save Dharma by misguiding the demonic peoples —

> रक्ष रक्षेति शरणं वदन्तो जग्मुरीश्वरम् मायामोहस्वरूपोऽसौ शुद्धोदनसुतोऽभवत् ॥ मोहयामास दैत्यांस्तांस्त्याजिता वेदधर्मकम् । ते च बौद्धाबभूवुर्हि तेभ्योऽन्यो वेदवर्जिताः ॥

> (Agni Puran : Chapter-16, Verse 1- 3)

Translation — All the Devas request Lord Vishnu to protect them! The the Lord says that he will incarnate as the son of Suddhodana, taking on a form that was enchanted by Maya. He enchanted the demons and got them to get rid of the practice of Vedic religion. All those Demonic peoples later became Buddhists and others also started abandoning the Vedas from them.

How exactly Lord Buddha looks like is mentioned in Agni Puran —

> शान्तात्मा लम्बकर्णश्च गौराङ्गश्चाम्बरावृतः।
> ऊर्ध्वपद्मस्थितो बुद्धो वरदाभयदायकः ॥
> (Agnipuran Chapter 49, Verse 8)

Translation — A calm personality, long ears, fair body, dressed in clothes, seated on a lotus blossoming upwards, Buddha in Abhayamudra and gives it to Varadabhaya.

(This form is of Gautam Buddha only)

Visnusahasranāma also mentioned the Glory of Buddhavtara —

> बुद्धो ध्यानजिताशेष देवदेवो जगत्प्रियः ॥ निरायुधो जगज्जैत्रः श्रीधरो दुष्टमोहनः । दैत्यवेदबहिःकर्त्ता वेदार्थश्रुतिगोपकः ॥ शौद्धोदनिर्दष्टदृष्टिः सुखदः सदसस्पतिः।

> (Visnusahasranāma )

Translation — He is Buddha who won over through meditation the Devas of all Devas.He is without weapon and conquered the world.

Dashavatar Charitam was written in 11th century CE by a Kashmiri scholar of high repute: Kshemendra (also known as Vyasadasa).He also written the same including their family details which was very accurate —

> (बुद्धावतारो नवमः) स सर्वसत्त्वोपकृतिप्रयत्नः कृपाकुलः शाक्यकुले विशाले। शुद्धोदनाख्यस्य नराधिपेन्दोर्धन्यस्य गर्भेऽवततार पत्न्याः >॥

> (Dashavatar Charitam)

Translation — Ninth incarnation Lord Buddha was filled with compassion in the vast Shakya family, striving to benefit all beings. The Lord appeared in the womb of the wife of the blessed King , whose name was Shuddhodana.

Lord Shri Hari prophecy about his incranation Buddha in Viṣṇudharma Purana —

> ततः कलियुगे घोरे सम्प्राप्तेऽब्जसमुद्भव । शुद्धोदनसुतो बुद्धो भविष्यामि विमत्सरः ॥ बौद्धं धर्ममुपाश्रित्य करिष्ये धर्मदेशनाम् । नराणामथ नारीणां दया भूतेषु दर्शयन् ॥

> (Vishnudharma Purana, Chapter 66, Verse - 68-71)

Translation — Then, in the terrible Kali-yuga, the I appeared . I shall become the son of Śudddhodana and I will preach the Buddhism, I will preach Dharma, I will preach kindness to men and women in beings.

Additional information - The description of the Buddha statue is found in the Agni Purana (49 :8-9) before the Kalki Purana, 'Lord Buddha is sitting on a high Padmamaya seat. In one hand he holds the posture of Varad and in the other the posture of Abhay. They are peaceful. His body color is fair and his ears are long. They are covered with beautiful yellow cloth.' He reached Kushinagar after preaching and he died there.
_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳_̳

This thing does not end here, but it is also described in Buddhist texts -
Lalitavistara Sutta ,JanmaParivarta –

> वज्र दृढ अभेद नारायण आत्मभावो गुरुवीर्यब्लोपत सोकम्पय: सर्वसत्तोन्त्य

English translation - Narayan himself appeared in the form of Buddha with strength, matured and thunderbolt body.

Five Siddha Maharishis when the seen the Lord Buddha and realised the divinity of Lord Buddha and they says that —

> रूपं वैश्रवणातिरेकवपुषं व्यक्तं कुबेरो ह्ययं आहो वज्रधरस्य चैव प्रतिमा चन्द्रोऽथ सूर्यो ह्ययम् । कामाग्राधिपतिश्च वा प्रतिकृती रुद्रस्य कृष्णस्य वा श्रीमान् लक्षणचित्रिताङ्गमनघो बुद्धोऽथ वा स्यादयम्॥

> (Lalitavistar -Krishigram Parivart, verse - 3 )

Translation — Is it the divine form of Kubera or the form of Indra? Is it the moon or the sun? Is it a replica of Kamadeva or Rudra? Isn't this Krishna only? Isn't this sinless man with Lakshmi, with strange divine organs, a Buddha?

When Lord Buddha born a great Sage come to the birth ceremony and he claims that he is Narayana himself. It is recorded in Buddhist text Lalitavistar-

> पुत्रस्ते वररूपपारमिगतो जातो महातेजवान् द्वात्रिंशद्वरलक्षणैः कवचितो नारायणस्थामवान् । तं द्रष्टुं हि ममेप्सितं नरपते सर्वार्थसिद्धं शिशुम् इत्यर्थं समुपागतोऽस्मि नृपते नास्त्यन्यकार्यं मम ॥

> (Lalitavistar- Janma-Parivarta, Verse - 66 )

Translation - 'O king! This son of yours is the height of supreme beauty, he has been born with great brilliance . He is endowed with thirty-two noble qualities and is endowed with the power of Narayan, whose all desires are self-fulfilling, it is my desire to see such a child named Sarvarthasiddha. I have come here for this reason, I have no other purpose than this.

And it is also mentioned in Chapter 15 of Buddhist text Hemadri Vratkhand-

> शुद्धोदनेन बुद्धोSभुत स्वयम पुत्रो जनार्दन

English translation - Janardana (Lord Vishnu) appears in the form of Swayam Shuddhodhana Buddha.

Additional information - Apart from these, the famous Buddhist writer and historian Kshemendra describes Buddha as the 9th incarnation of Vishnu in his text named Dashavatara Charitaram. Another text, the Dasharatha Jataka Buddhist Ramayana, describes Lord Rama as an earlier birth of Buddha. That is, Buddha is said to be an incarnation of Lord Rama. In Sri Lankan Buddhist texts, Buddha is also described as an incarnation of Lord Rama. In the first sutta of the Sri Lankan Buddhist text Lankavatara Sutta, Ravana is described as a Bodhisattva, a follower of Buddha.
Please note - This is my own research, while reading Puranas and Buddhists text , I collected these verses. Buddha is Vishnu incranation it's a truth.. There are many Shankaracharya who on the basis of kalki Purana or bhavishya Purana 3-2 verses , they claim that there are two different buddhas but that was totally wrong. Buddha is only one that is GAUTAM BUDDHA .

**Question - Why Lord Vishnu take Buddhavtar?**

Ans - Due to some effect of kaliyug peoples started mis-interpreting Vedas words and started Narbali (Human Sacrifice) , Horses sacrifice, and by mis-interpreting Vedas words too much discrimination started. It is mentioned in our Shastras also-

> VII 6:180-89

> वेदा विनिंदिता येन विलोक्य पशुहिंसनम् सकृपेन त्वया येन तस्मै बुद्धाय ते नमः ॥१८८॥

So it is required that Vedas study stop for sometime to manage this Kali-yuga effect so Narayana in the form of Buddha gave the philosophy of Sunyavaad (nothingness) so Vedas got closed....and Brahmin started spreading Sunyavaad philosophy... But after sometime it is required to open all the Vedic scriptures to establish the Vedic Dharma again. So according to Padma Puran Viṣṇu request Shiva to take Avtar on earth as Adi Shankaracharya to rebuttal the Sunyavaad philosophy and open all the Vedas... After sometime Lord Vayu(Sripad Madhavacharya) take Avtar to establish the Narayana bhakti-tattava on earth.

> Hope my answer satisfied you

Comment: Superb answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In puranas Buddha is mentioned one of the ten avatars of Lord Vishnu, usually the ninth avatar. 
 The puranas that mention Buddha as the avatar of Vishnu are:
Harivamsa (1.41)
Vishnu Purana (3.18)
Bhagavata Purana (1.3.24, 2.7.37, 11.4.23) 
Garuda Purana (1.1, 2.30.37, 3.15.26)
Agni Purana (16)
Naradiya Purana (2.72)
Linga Purana (2.71)
Padma Purana (3.252)

The Vishnu Purana mentions the sequential order from the  oldest to the newest  among the puranas

> [Vishnu Purana - 3.6.20-23]
>   1. Brahma Purana
>   2. Padma Purana
>   3. Vishnu Purana
>   4. Shiva Purana
>   5. Bhagavata Purana
>   6. Narada Purana
>   7. Markandeya Purana
>   8. Agni Purana
>   9. Bhavisya Purana
>   10. Brahmavaivarta Purana
>   11. Linga Purana
>   12. Varaha Purana
>   13. Skanda Purana
>   14. Vamana Purana
>   15. Kurma Purana
>   16. Mastya Purana
>   17. Garuda Purana
>   18. Brahmanda Purana

According to Vishnu Puranas order Padma Purana is the oldest among Puranas which mention Buddha as Vishnu's avatar. Padma Purana 3.252