# Where is this verse mentioned?

Tags: reference-request, buddha

VII 6:180-89

वेदा विनिंदिता येन विलोक्य पशुहिंसनम् सकृपेन त्वया येन तस्मै बुद्धाय ते नमः ॥१८८॥

[This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/52919/32378) verse is from which book?

Comment: It's from Padma Purāṇa ([7.6.188](https://archive.org/details/sri-padma-maha-purana-part-7-kriya-khanda-sanskrti-printed-khemraj-jangamwadi-math-collection/page/n31/mode/2up)) - *vedāvininditāyenavilokyapaśuhiṁsanam / sakṛpenatvayāyenatasmaibuddhāyatenamaḥ //*

Comment: @Bingming if one asks for reference of buddha outside puran. Where can he get

Comment: Well, there are so many śāstras which refer to Buddha, what are you looking for really?

Comment: @Bingming I am looking for evidence that gautam buddha is avtar of vishnu [which is not from purans]

Comment: Many other sources mentioning such an info, refer to Purāṇas (or cite their relevant ślokas). I don't know why you are undertaking such an exercise.

Comment: @Bingming because I am searching for prediction with proper noun in kaliyug that happened in reality from mahabharat and ramayan

Comment: @Hope Vyasa Mahabharata gives some preedictions in the end for Kali Yuga. Why or how does it matter whether Buddha is or is not an avatar of Vishnu? i.e. if you keep questioning and answering, where does it end? Is Allah an avatar of Vishnu is the next question? Eternal search is not recommended in Hinduism (otherwise we wouldn't have Upanishads handed down to us). SamhayAtma vinashyati is not just a catch phrase.

Comment: @VijaySharma if buddha is avtar of vishnu. Then mahabharat predict kaliyug with proper noun. Also it's sanshay(Doubtful) atma not samay atma vinasyati

Comment: @VijaySharma found                         
  काषायवस्रसंवीतो मुण्डितः शुक्लदन्तवान्।
शुद्धोदनसुतो बुद्धो मोहयिष्यामि मानवान्।। 12-348-43a
12-348-43b
शूद्राः सुद्धेषु भुज्यन्ते मयि बुद्धत्वमागते।
भविष्यन्ति नराः सर्वे बुद्धाः काषायसंवृताः।। 12-348-44a
12-348-44 https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D-12-%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5-348

Comment: @Hope that was a typo (autocorrect) re samshayAtma. If you speak to Hindu scholars, whether in Kashi or in Gorakhpur or in Tirupathi, there is no concensus that the Buddha referred to in those texts is the same one we know as Gautama Siddhartha today. Moreover, BuddhAha also means Intelligent ones (plural); Buddhe is with vibhakti too, so its not a proper noun. The trouble with eternal search is at some point you will see what you want to see. And that is the maya:)

Comment: @VijaySharma the verse also has reference to father of Buddha. You can translate it. He was dressed in brown clothes, shaved and had white teeth.  I, the Buddha, the son of Shuddhodana, shall bewitch men.  12-348-43a 12-348-43b The Sudras are enjoyed among the pure when I have attained Buddhism.  All men will be enlightened and covered with saffron. ;

Comment: So, hinduism is true religion because only God/Godly sage can predict future with proper noun (father of Buddha/Buddha)

Comment: @Hope They seem to be interpolations. If you look to that extent, then Valmiki Ramayana in 109th Sarga refers to Buddha too, and shows Buddha in a bad light. Yet the correct translations are those that translate Buddha to an Intellectual, and not gautama Siddhartha (he was give Buddha as a title, indicating what that word referred to in pre-Gautama Siddhartha era in Bharat). Now we cannot say that this verse alone is an interpolation but the ones you quoted are not, can we!

Comment: @VijaySharma my opinion: interpolation is not possible. Either a scripture is false or true. Because if interpolation is added in magadh, bihar, Punjab Or any place how can it reach all parts of india and world. Like a fake pandit added a verse in odisha how can it transmit all over India+ in that verse of ramayn, buddha=mere intellect.

Comment: @Hope you seem to be unaware of the strict traditions Brahmins used to adhere to pre-british rule (some do so even now). One requirement of Brahmins (when kingdoms existed up until the 19th century), was that they need to keep travelling from village to village, town to town and not reside in any one place forever. Adi Shankara was neither the first nor the last Brahmin to traverse India, Brahmins were supposed to do it. That is how ideas, new theories, and changes to the texts were carried out. Moreoever, if you read, you will see different interpolations exist in texts of different origings.

Comment: Just to confirm: You want a reference for the fact that gautam buddha is an avatar of vishnu that comes from a non-Puranic text? I might be able to find one; what upanishads or samhitas or vedas would you accept?

Comment: @CDR leave it I found